# Why was my question moved?

Tags: discussion, support

This upsets me, I am already in an upset mood due to my question then someone comes along, closes my question and moves it to legal. Then people in legal said no this belongs in parenting and then butchered the hell out of my question to contain only the TINY portion that was dealing with legal. I WANT TO KNOW HOW A PARENT SHOULD HANDLE THIS SITUATION! Not just the legal aspect but should I file charges? Should I go to school and break the little boys neck?? I want my question back over here and I want PARENTS to tell me how they would handle my situation. I have a meeting with the DEAN in 2 hours to discuss this and as it stands I am out for blood because I have no one telling me I'm over reacting or maybe i should look at this differently. What gives?

https://parenting.stackexchange.com/posts/28897/revisions

I rolledback the guys edit on legal but I am sure they will just butcher my question again... I do not understand why my question is being forced to a location that does not want it.........

https://law.stackexchange.com/questions/17041/bully-broke-my-sons-bone-what-next

Answer (score 3):

Your post was very much off topic here. 3 of your questions in that post require legal guidance, and the other has to be answered by the head teacher. So at best it would be put on hold and closed here.

> File charges? Should/can I file assault charges?

Speak to a lawyer.

> Who pays the medical bills? I do not feel we should have to pay the medical bills. The boy did this to my son, is the school or boy's parents liable?

Speak to a lawyer.

> Is the school or parents liable? Who will ensure proper justice is served?

Only a lawyer can tell you.

> Proper school punishment? Should the kid not be punished? Should he be suspended or expelled?

Speak to the head teacher.

I hoped Law would give it an opportunity to have an answer, and they have focused on the legal aspects in order to be able to answer. If you roll back their edits, they'll just close it as it doesn't fit any more.

Comment: I guess I wasn't really caring about the lawyers opinion but more of a parental instinct. I was looking more for, File Charges? Well the kids is only in 6th grade and probably didn't mean it so take it easy on him. Or.. The boy broke your kids bone, take things to the max, press for assault, expulsion the whole nine yards. The liability part I was hoping others have gone through it and tell me "hey when it happened with my kid the school covered it" .. things like this, i am not looking for legal advise, I'm looking for parental advise to make sure I am not going to far.

Comment: Since my answer is closed in both locations I will put the results here. The boy will have 7 days of suspension, the school will pay for anything my insurance won't cover. They will monitor the situation between the boys to make sure there are no more occurrences. We are not pressing charges due to boys being boys. If something else happens I will explore more serious action. (This is what happened, but also describes the kinda answer I was hoping to get, will less details since this is in a comment..)

Comment: See, the problem here is that those possible answers you were going for are entirely opinion based, and that's not within the SE remit. Neither would have been the "correct answer" and any opinion would be just that. I'm glad you had a head teacher who seems to be taking a sensible approach though.

Comment: Thank you, me too. I agree it was opinion based, but I don't see that as a bad thing. I just needed help so I reached out to a community I am familiar with. Its not like I was asking a homework question in SO ;/ I learned, I'll keep my questions to myself from now on lol.

Comment: Oh, it's not a bad thing. It's just not an SE thing.